# What happens with the local virtual machine when I shutdown my PC

Tags: windows, virtualization, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have an Hyper-V virtual machine running on my PC and I'm in the middle of an installation wizard.

but I have to shutdown my PC where the Hyper-V is running.

My question is, what happens with the running state of the virtual machine after I restart my PC? I have to save the running state of this virtual machine... Is this only possible by making a snapshot?

Comment: This entirely depends on how you configured the virtual machine.  If you configured the virtual machine to create snapshots when the virtual machine is turned off, then it will create snapshots, automatically when the Windows starts to shutdown since Windows will tell Hyper-V to shut down the virtual machine

Answer (score 1):

You can go into the Settings for the VM that you care about, and make sure it is set to "Save the Virtual Machine State." When your physical machine shuts down it will suspend the VM and when you bring it back up it'll be in the same state as when you shutdown.

See below for the screen you are looking for. It's at the bottom of the left hand panel.

[image: Setting Screen]